# Can anyone explain to me why was my question closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing

I posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360650/showing-every-p-subgroup-of-order-pi-is-in-a-subgroup-of-order-pi1) question which at first seemed related to the linked question though I was trying to complete a method. I then edited the question so that it serves that purpose yet it was still closed, and linked to a question which has not the answer. Can someone clarify why that occured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it has been reopened now. I don't know about this specific case, but sometimes mistakes/misunderstandings happen (we all are human, hopefully :-)). If you think a question has been closed wrongfully, asking a question on meta (just like you did) is the right way to go.

(But don't use the support tag, use discussion instead).

Comment: Thank you for the information. My aggressive tone was maybe due to the fact that when I reworded the question it only had 3 votes to be closed.

Comment: @user10444 BTW, I would suggest using our [reopen request thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes) instead of posting a new meta question.